# Bringing wayland on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Can any one tell implementation of  wayland on raspberry pi. Also some basic concept about how
wayland interacts with kernel.What are main components involved in it.

Comment: This is a pretty current issue, ask on #wayland.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the following links for basic understanding of linux graphics stack and wayland implementation in the graphics stack.

http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/06/the-linux-graphics-stack

http://lca2009.linux.org.au/slides/205.pdf

Hope this would be useful.